# Making standard console appear in allegro

Tags: c++, console, allegro

When I run allegro program there isnt standard text console. How can I make it appear, so I can use cout and cin then?
Im using Dev-Cpp and allegro 4.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

- Create the application as a console application

[image]

- Use the Win32 API to allocate and attach a console when needed:

  - [Creation of a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [Attaching to a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681953(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [Closing a Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682048(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thats all. Great answer, thanx.

Comment: I found another way (simillar to ur 1st one), just change in the project options from win32 gui to win32 console.